# Nombre de los acentos y otras marcas ortográficas

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, ortografía

En otra pregunta hice una mala traducción al inglés. Quise referirme al acento gráfico (´) como *tilde*, pero la traducción correcta es *diacritic*. Esto me confundió un poco.

Quiero entonces consultar acerca de los nombres "estándar" para referirse a la acentuación en español y si hay **variedades regionales** al respecto.

En **Chile** usamos los siguiente:

- **Acento**: aumento de la intensidad del sonido en una sílaba.
- **Tilde**: pequeña raya diagonal sobre una vocal.
- **Aguda**: palabra con acento en la última sílaba.
- **Grave**: en la penúltima.
- **Esdrújula**: en la antepenúltima.
- Acento **dierético**: tilde que rompe diptóngos.
- Acento **diacrítico**: tilde que distingue homófonos.

En el habla corriente suele haber algún relajo en la distinción entre acento y tilde, pero nadie se confundiría realmente.

Además, a la rayita horizontal (-) le decimos **guión**; a la coma flotante ('), **apóstrofe**; y a los puntos de la u, **cremillas**. Desconozco el nombre de la **tilde de la eñe** (~).

Pido disculpas porque no es una pregunta que involucre algún auténtico problema, pero me parece interesante.

Comment: En Argentina llamamos **diéresis** a los puntos sobre la ü (u otra vocal); muy pocos entenderían si lo llamás **crema** o **cremilla**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay una confusión acá que valdrá la pena aclarar antes de traducir los términos.

Tilde tiene la [acepción](http://dle.rae.es/tilde) según la RAE de ser lo que en inglés es un *diacritic*, o sea, cualquier signo ortográfico que sirva para diferenciar dos letras. Todo esto está bien, pero nos topamos con lo que mencionás, y es que para muchos, una tilde es [el acento ortográfico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acento_ortogr%C3%A1fico) en español. Así es como yo entendería el término y como es usado en mi dialecto (y al parecer en el tuyo también).

El término [diacrítico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signo_diacr%C3%ADtico) también tiene el [significado](http://dle.rae.es/tilde) del término en inglés *diacritic*. Cualquier signo ortográfico que le cambie el valor a una letra "normal".

Y lo último que podría causar confusión es que la palabra `tilde` también existe en inglés, y representa este símbolo: `~`, a lo cual se le llama *virgulilla* (o *tilde de la ñ*) en español.

Habiendo ya aclarado la posible confusión, aquí están los términos con sus traducciones y algunas notas:

- **acento (prosódico)**: llamado *[stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_%28linguistics%29)* en inglés.
- **tilde**: con la acepción de acento agudo en el contexto del español es llamada *[accent (mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_mark)* lo cual redirecciona a *diacritic* en Wikipedia, siendo la otra posible acepción.
- **(palabra) aguda**: estos serán términos más propios del campo de la lingüística [*oxytone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barytone), mientras que casualmente se dirá simplemente *stressed on the last syllable*.
- **(palabra) grave**: al igual que la anterior ([*paroxytone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paroxytone))
- **(palabra) esdrújula**: [*proparoxytone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proparoxytone)
- **guión**: [*hyphen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen)
- **apóstrofo (o apóstrofe)**: apostrophe
- **diéresis (o cremillas)**: *[dieresis (diaeresis)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic))*

Comment: Muy buena información. Gracias por aclararme la confusión y compartir la traducción. La palabra _virgulilla_ es realmente una curiosidad, la voy a usar para jactarme.

Answer (score 3):

Acá en **México** los nombres van así:

- **Sílaba tónica**: la sílaba que suena más fuerte en una palabra.
- **Sílaba átona**: las sílabas que no tienen valor tónico.
- **Acento**: marca que denota a la sílaba tónica o diferencia una palabra de otra. [En México no se usa la palabra *tilde*]
- **Agudas**: palabras con la sílaba tónica al final.
- **Graves**: con la sílaba tónica en la penúltima sílaba.
- **Esdrújulas**: con la sílaba tónica en la antepenúltima sílaba.
- **Sobreesdrújulas**: con la sílaba tónica antes de la antepenúltima sílaba.

Sobre los demás signos:

- (-): **Guión** o **guión medio** cuando se hace diferencia del guión bajo sobre todo a la hora de dar una dirección de correo.
- (_): **Guión bajo**.
- (/): **Diagonal**.
- (¨): **Diéresis**.
- ("): **Comillas**.
- ('): Las personas generalmente no conocen la palabra **apóstrofe** y simplemente se dice **comilla**, o se aclara **una comilla**. Pero el nombre oficial es ese, *apóstrofe*.

Y en cuanto a la tilde de la Ñ se llama **virgulilla**, pero no hay mucho problema en cuanto a no saberlo al ser una letra como un todo y no un signo aislado como sí es el caso del portugués.