# Circumflex or Acute over O and proper translation

Tags: traducción, acentuación, letras, lenguaje-jurídico

I am reproducing 2 concealed handgun posters and they have Spanish language translations. One of them has this:

> DE ACUERDO CON LA SECCIÓN 30.07, CÓDIGO PENAL

(English: PURSUANT TO SECTION 30.07, PENAL CODE

and the other has this:

> CONFORME A LA SECCIÓN 30.06 DEL CÔDIGO PENAL

(English: PURSUANT TO SECTION 30.06 PENAL CODE)

Which would be correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such *circumflex* accent in Spanish.

The only diacritics available are:

- **acute accent**

  - sección
  - código
- **dieresis**

  - ungüento
  - pingüino

There is the letter **ñ** (with some sort of a diacritic), but we could say that is just a different letter than **n**.

Comment: Fun trivia: Spanish did have a circumflex for just the 18th century. Not that it changes anything of what you say, and OP's original certainly has a typo; but I didn't know.

Comment: Just for information...the **~** character over the **n** to form **ñ** is called **"virgulilla"** See all these names  here http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10730/nombre-de-los-acentos-y-otras-marcas-ortogr%C3%A1ficas

Comment: I thought so. This came from my wife's corporate office as a poster and it was 24" X 34" and I am converting it to 11" X 17".